# Exporting animation separately to glTF 2.0

Tags: animation, gltf

How do I export each animation separately in gLTF 2.0 format? I have a Blender file with a lot of objects and animations, but I just want to export some animations.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This might already have an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228666/18161

Comment: Note that exporting an animation to glTF does require that the animation be associated with an Armature or an Empty, at least – exporting animation to glTF without it targeting anything isn't really possible.